# Count characters in input

Tags: c

I'm trying to output the count of characters in input like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count characters in input; 1st version */
main(){
    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;

    printf("%ld\n",nc);
}
```

But it doesn't output anything. What's wrong?

Comment: input EOF(crtl+D or ctrl+Z(windows)).

Comment: I thought it was enter that's why. Thanks!

Comment: only a friendly suggestion -- use explicit main declaration as it is the only valid notation in stadards: `int main(void) {/*...*/ return 0;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're not inputting anything. EOF doesn't mean that there are no characters available; getchar() just waits for input. EOF means you have it CTRL+Z or CTRL+D.

Answer (score 1):

[Someone asked the same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565663/while-c-getchar-eof-not-terminating)
It should answer your question, good explanation by many people

summary of the source and my answer:
EOF indicates "end of file".  Use CTRL-D (unix-style systems) or CTRL-Z (Windows), and the loop will terminate

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  long nc = 0;

  do
  {
    printf("%ld chars read so far, hit any key or Ctrl-D/Ctrl-Z to end.\n", nc);
    ++nc;
  } while (getchar() != EOF)

  printf("total number of chars entered: %ld\n", nc);  
}
```