# Program stops running after while loop

Tags: c

So, it has been some time since I last programmed in C, and now I am trying to get back into C again, but I am having trouble with my program. The program is very simple, I use getchar to store chars in a char array, but for some reason the program stops running after my while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int main(){
    char c;
    char input[MAXLINE];
    int i = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
         input[i] = c;
         ++i;
    }
    printf("Still running");
}
```

So, my program doesn't print "Still running".

Comment: Could it be that the input is more than `MAXLINE` (1000) characters?

Comment: Do you actually send an `EOF` to break the loop?

Comment: Also, [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int`. This is actually very important.

Comment: What happens if you add a `newline` so `printf("Still running\n");`

Comment: If `char` is unsigned, `EOF` (-1) will not be detected, use `int c` which is what `getchar` returns.

Comment: No, the input isn't too long, I used a very short input.
I changed it to an int, it still doesn't work.
Also, adding a newline doesn't help.
Shouldn't there always be one at the end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) Not terminating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565663/while-c-getchar-eof-not-terminating)

Comment: Buffer not necessarily flushed to output until a `newline` is sent. When inserting debugging cues, this can cause much confusion.

Comment: What are you typing to end the session, and what is the OS?

Comment: Lastly, are you sure the program "stops running"? It doesn't just pause? Can you please be a little more specific? If you run from a command prompt, do you get the prompt back when the program "stops running", or does it just sit there waiting for more input? Have you tried debugging the program? Adding more `printf` calls to see what happens? Step through the code line by line in a debugger? Do you press enter and *then* the end-of-line keypress?

Comment: EOF is of type int, not char.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, doing CTRL + Z helps does it!

Comment: In Windows console, the `Ctrl-Z` must be *the first character after a newline*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send EOF (Ctrl+D for *nix Ctrl+Z for Win), it will show the Still running.

```
root@Linux-VirtualBox:~/program/progEdit# ./stktest.o 
sdf 
fdf 
sdf 
Still runningroot@Linux-VirtualBox:~/program/progEdit#
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program only works by luck, because `getchar` returns an `int` not a `char`. The reason for this is that `getchar` may return `EOF`, which is not necessarily representable as a `char`.

To fix this bug, you need to replace `char c` with `int c`.

Comment: Yes, that was one of the problems, however it didn't work by only doing this, I also had to do Ctrl + Z after I had entered my input. I'll still give you an upvote since you mentioned one of the flaws in my code.