# Character counting program doesnt work as it should

Tags: c

I created a C program in my Windows XP PC using Dev-C++5.11. It's the one that I saw as a typical character counting program and it goes as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF) {
        ++nc;
    }
    printf("%ld", nc);
}
```

It compiled without problems but it works as it should ONLY when among the characters I press I include the enter button (`\n`). If I dont it either prints 0 or nothing at all. I tried include other characters like tab or backspace but still nothing. I am using ctrl+c to terminate it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) Not terminating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565663/while-c-getchar-eof-not-terminating)

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work "as it should", but it works only way it could, since you are using getchar() function which waits for "enter button"

Comment: @DarkoDjuric: `getchar()` does not wait for "enter", it waits for input to actually appear at `stdin`. The two are very different things.

Comment: @DevSolar Is there any other way to make it "actually appear at stdin" when getchar() function is used?

Comment: @DarkoDjuric: You need to disable the buffering 8on the input side*. This can be a setting for your terminal software. Or you might use an API that communicates directly with the terminal buffer, so-called "raw input". Windows has `<conio.h>` supporting an [unbuffered function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) `getch()`. Unix has (if installed) the ncurses library, `<curses.h>`, with a [function of the same name](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) (but which needs some additional plumbing to "work right"). In any case, *there is no such functionality in the standard*...

Comment: (ctd.) ...because the standard does not deal in terminals. This is up to third-party libs. ;-)

Comment: You should pay attention to compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffered input.

When you type in input, it gets buffered by the terminal (cmd.exe, xterm, whatever). Your program is still not "seeing" any of that input at this point. Only after you press enter does the terminal send the buffer contents to your program.

If you terminate the program before you press enter, nothing ever gets send / processed.

Answer (score 0):

Your program should work fine.  Try running it by redirecting a file into it as:

```
myprogram < somefile
```

The problem you observe comes from the handling of end of file by the terminal.  You signal the end of file by typing `Ctrl-Z<enter>` in Windows and `Ctrl-D` in Unix.

Note however that you should write your program this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF) {
        ++nc;
    }
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getchar() reads until EOF; so, thus, you won't see your printf() output until the while loop exits (that is, when the getchar() function returns EOF).

In order to send EOF, you can hit CTRL+D. Try typing in your input and then hitting CTRL+D and see if that works. At least in UNIX / OS X this will send EOF. You could also compare characters and if a certain key is pressed, you exit the loop and see your count.

If you're piping in output from another program, then this should work fine as it will receive EOF after the output is done piping into it. For instance, cat file | ./counterprogram