# ^Z character is written to the file or not?

Tags: c, windows, file-handling, fputs

I am writing text to a file using the following program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int ch;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "w");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Press Ctrl+D to stop \n\n");

    printf("Enter text: ");

    while( (ch=getchar()) != EOF )
    {
        fputc(ch, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Let's say the input is:

```
Press Ctrl+D to stop \n\n

Enter text: this is a test
^Z
```

My question is the end of file character (ASCII value 26) will be written to the file or not ?

Comment: Your question appears to assume Windows. Not even that, but DOS. Should adjust your tags.

Comment: How did you conclude that `^Z` is the ASCII character represented by 26?

Comment: @RSahu It is actually Ctrl+Z

Comment: You could simply view the file in a hex editor / hexdump utility.

Comment: @Cody, I understood that. On what platform does `Ctrl+Z` translate to the ASCII character represented by 26?

Comment: @RSahu Window of course

Comment: Usually shells convert these key combination to provide certain actions ctrl-z means SIGSTOP is sent to your program on Linux at least. Ctrl-D is [EOF](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/)

Comment: No Ctrl-Z here http://www.asciitable.com/ nor here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII.

Comment: @NulledPointer so in Linux nothing will be written after "this is a test" ?

Comment: As per your program it will quit without writing anything in the file because ctrl-D means EOF as i said before

Comment: OT: It should be `int main(void)` at least, BTW.

Comment: @NulledPointer i verified using a hex editor that it is not writing ^Z to the file. But there is another problem. Let's say i entered `abc^Z` followed by a newline. In this case, the character ^Z is written to the file. Since getchar() stops reading as soon as it encountered ^Z it should stop reading character but here it is not stopping. Why ?

Comment: @alk Actually there is: (Wikipedia page) Dec 26, `SUB`, `^Z` - Follow [the link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) and you get *"Standard keyboards transmit this code when the Ctrl and Z keys are pressed simultaneously (...)."*.

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18582991/694576 or even more detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7373386/694576

Comment: @RSahu basically every platform with a control key. Z is 0x5A (decimal 90). Clear the 0x40 bit and you get 0x1A (decimal 26). Or just remember that Z is the 26th letter. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified using a hex editor in Windows `^Z` character is not written to the file.